# Can I use a fold function to implement pack functionality?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm working on the following problem:

> Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists. If a list
>   contains repeated elements they should be placed in separate sublists.
>   Example:
>
> scala> pack(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e,
>   'e)) res0: List[List[Symbol]] = List(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a), List('b),
>   List('c, 'c), List('a, 'a), List('d), List('e, 'e, 'e, 'e))

I am wondering whether it can be implemented using foldRight. So far I can only make a recursive solution like below work:

```
def pack(list: List[Char]) = {
  def checkNext(a: List[List[Char]], prev: Char, l: List[Char]): List[List[Char]] = l match {
    case Nil => a
    case h::tail if h == prev => checkNext((h::a.head)::a.tail,h,tail)
    case h::tail => checkNext(List(h)::a,h,tail)
  }
  checkNext(List(List[Char](list.last)), list.last, list.init.reverse) 
}
```

Comment: Yes! It's definitely possible. Do you want a solution, hints, etc.?

Comment: If you look at the Wikipedia page for `fold`, you will find a proof that `fold` is a general method for iteration. So, everything that can be done with `foreach` or recursion can also be done with `fold`. So, the answer to *any* question of the form "Can I use a `fold` function to implement XYZ functionality" is *always* going to be "Yes!" (provided that XYZ is related to recursion or iteration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely! I find it to be very natural to use `fold`s to accumulate a complex result from iterating a sequence. Essentially, it works the same as what you're doing now, except the matching on the list is provided to you by `fold`, and you just provide the processing for the cases. I'm not sure if you wanted an actual answer, so I'll try to give you a couple hints.

Think of the type of your final result. Now think of what value of that type would be the result of applying your process to an empty sequence. That's your first argument to `foldRight`/`foldLeft`.

Now you have to define what to do to extend your accumulator for each item you process. It seems to me you have two cases: either you've encountered a new letter that you haven't seen before or you're adding another instance to an existing list. You can use some fancy matching to detect which case you're in.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def pack(list: List[Char]) = list.foldLeft(List.empty[List[Char]]) { case (acc, next) =>
  acc.headOption.flatMap(_.headOption) match {
    case Some(x) if x == next => (acc.head :+ next) +: acc.tail
    case _ => List(next) +: acc
  }
}.reverse
```

I used `flatMap` to join the two checks for whether there's a list at all yet and whether the a list for the current character exists. I find `foldLeft` to be more intuitive and it also has the added benefit of being tail recursive on `List`.

The result:

> scala> pack(List('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'd',
>   'e', 'e', 'e', 'e'))
>
> res1: List[List[Char]] = List(List(a, a, a, a),
>   List(b), List(c, c), List(a, a), List(d), List(e, e, e, e))

Comment: I'd love to see your implementation - I got mine working but it would be nice to compare!

Comment: @cm22 Implementation added!

Comment: @acjay I would rather use prepend instead of append, meaning: `next :: acc.head`/`next +: acc.head` rather than `(acc.head :+ next)`. Since all elements are equal it does not change the semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of `fold`:

```
def pack[A](xs: List[A]): List[List[A]] =
  xs.foldRight(List[List[A]]()){
    case (x, (ys@(y::_)) :: rs) if x == y => (x::ys) :: rs
    case (x, ys) => List(x) :: ys
  }
```

However, I prefer the recursive one:

```
def pack2[A](xs: List[A]): List[List[A]] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x::_ => val (hs, ts) = xs.span(x==); hs::pack2(ts)
}
```

The recursive one is **clearer and shorter** than the `fold` version, in addition it is **faster**!

```
scala> def time(n: Int)(call : => Unit): Long = {
     |   var cnt = 0
     |   val start = System.currentTimeMillis
     |   while(cnt < n) {
     |     cnt += 1
     |     call
     |   }
     |   System.currentTimeMillis - start
     | }
time: (n: Int)(call: => Unit)Long

scala> val xs = ("A"*100 + "B"*1000 + "C"*10 + "DEFGH"*1000).toList
xs: List[Char] = List(A, A, A...)

scala> time(10000){ pack(xs) }
res3: Long = 19961

scala> time(10000){ pack2(xs) }
res4: Long = 4382
```

And named @acjay's version as `pack3`:

```
scala> def pack3(list: List[Char]) = list.foldLeft(List.empty[List[Char]]) { case (acc, next) =>
     |   acc.headOption.flatMap(_.headOption) match {
     |     case Some(x) if x == next => (acc.head :+ next) +: acc.tail
     |     case _ => List(next) +: acc
     |   }
     | }.reverse
pack3: (list: List[Char])List[List[Char]]

scala> time(10000){ pack3(xs) }
res5: Long = 420946

scala> pack3(xs) == pack2(xs)
res6: Boolean = true

scala> pack3(xs) == pack(xs)
res7: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation by Martin Odersky

```scala
def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match{
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: xs1 =>
        val (first, rest) = xs span (y => y == x)
        first :: pack(rest)
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue?

Comment: This is the same solution as posted by @Eastsun (see `pack2()`).